# Does Hibernate 2nd-Level cache invalidate when running a JPQL update statement

Tags: hibernate, second-level-cache

When you run a JPQL update or delete query, is Hibernate smart enough to invalidate the 2nd-level cache for the entity that is changed?

Contrived example:

You have the JPQL:

```
update Product p set p.status = 'S' where p.name like 'Monitor%'
```

If you currently have products in the 2nd-level cache when that statement is run, will Hibernate invalidate all products from the cache or does it do nothing to the cache and the products in the 2nd level cache are now invalid?

Just FYI... I'm using JBoss 5.1 with Hibernate and JBossCache

Comment: Interesting. I think you can check that - set showSql=true (or if not using JPA, the hibernate property for showing the sql output on the console), and see if hibernate fetches again from the database an entity that was just updated with hql.

Comment: That would only tell you if it reloaded those items into cache, which I don't imagine it does. What it wouldn't tell you is if it invalidated the cache so all instances of that entity would have to be reloaded from the database. I guess I'll just have to do a test and find out. I was hoping someone here would have a quick answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running my own test and running across [this bug](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-3818) it appears that it will invalidate the ENTIRE second-level cache, not just the second-level cache for any entities involved in the update.